# Upstream pressure on solenoid valve

Tags: relay, solenoid, pressure

Does a solenoid valve consume more current when the pressure in the connected pipes is more than normal?

Comment: You should read the datasheet. The pressure should be less than the maximum specified for the valve.

Comment: I have read the datasheet and the maximum pressure handling capacity is 10 bars and the avg pressure created on the valve is around 2 bars. So the pressure is not an issue but I want to know the effects of more pressure than rated.

Comment: More pressure than rated may cause the valve to break, leak, fail to close or open. If you want to know the effects of more pressure than rated you have to do some tests by yourself. The manufacturer would not guarantee a certain behavior beyond the rated pressure.